# Why is My Ubuntu 19 Installation Not Detecting My Integrated Webcam? Cheese & Chrome Seem to Not Be Able to Access It

Tags: drivers, google-chrome, 19.04, webcam, cheese

After countless attempts of fixing my machine, I've finally decided it's time to ask the Internet for help. Basically, my computer is unable to detect or use my integrated webcam....

*at all.*

Here is the output of the lsusb command:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f3:031d Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And, this is the output of the lspci command:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev e3)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller (rev 03)
06:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 59)
07:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
07:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
08:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 845M] (rev a2)
```

The computer is running **Ubuntu 19.04**

Computer Model:

Core™ i7-5500U CPU @ 2.40GHz × 4

Intel® HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2) / NV118

Gnome Version: 3.32.1

64-bit machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I was able to debug most of the issues with dmesg logs, etc. It seems like using the following commands (as well as constantly refreshing dmesg on another terminal window) helped me out quite a bit (I can't say **for sure** that they'll work in any situation, but it's definitely worth a shot)

```
sudo rmmod uvcvideo

sudo modprobe uvcvideo
```

Note: I'm not exactly 100% sure of the importance of using `sudo` here. It might not even be necessary - it might just be verbose.

Comment: Just for those wondering, if your [cheese](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Cheese) doesn't work via the GUI application, it might be worth it to check through with the `cheese` command. Personally, the gui wasn't working in the beginning, so I just launched it with the terminal... and it worked!!! After a few minutes(maybe Ubuntu refreshed?) the webcam started working through the gui as well.